# Animation delay for some buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I write this codes for my buttons that on a wrap panel.
I want to show them with opacity animation but when compiler reach to s.begin(); it don't work and show me an error.
please guide me to fix this codes.
I write them with help of others codes on the internet.
and one thing is because I don't know how to make an delay for animation I write those ifs.

```
    private void ShowButtonsAnime()
    {
        DoubleAnimation opacityanime = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = 0,
            To = 100,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000)
        };
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityanime, new PropertyPath(Ellipse.OpacityProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityanime, AccountBtn);
        Storyboard s = new Storyboard();
        s.Children.Add(opacityanime);
        s.Begin();
        if (AccountBtn.Opacity == 100)
        {
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityanime, ObserveDatabtn);
            s.Children.Add(opacityanime);
            s.Begin();
        }
        if (ObserveDatabtn.Opacity == 100)
        {
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityanime, Formsbtn);
            s.Children.Add(opacityanime);
            s.Begin();
        }
        if (Formsbtn.Opacity == 100)
        {
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityanime, Resource);
            s.Children.Add(opacityanime);
            s.Begin();
        }
        if (Resource.Opacity == 100)
        {
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityanime, BalanceDatabtn);
            s.Children.Add(opacityanime);
            s.Begin();
        }
        if (BalanceDatabtn.Opacity == 100)
        {
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityanime, ReportsSettingsbtn);
            s.Children.Add(opacityanime);
            s.Begin();
        }
        if (ReportsSettingsbtn.Opacity == 100)
        {
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityanime, Settingbtn);
            s.Children.Add(opacityanime);
            s.Begin();
        }
    }
```

And the error is :
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No target was specified for 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a Solution for my own problem and that is we can use those codes on loaded event of every control likes coeds I write here and we can make delay by writes ifs.

```
    private void AccountBtn_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation Opacityanimation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = 0,
            To = 100,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90)
        };
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Opacityanimation, new PropertyPath(Ellipse.OpacityProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(Opacityanimation, AccountBtn);
        Storyboard s = new Storyboard();
        s.Children.Add(Opacityanimation);
        s.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void AccountBtn_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation Opacityanimation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = 0,
        To = 100,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90)
    };
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Opacityanimation, new PropertyPath(Ellipse.OpacityProperty));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(Opacityanimation, AccountBtn);
    Storyboard s = new Storyboard();
    s.Children.Add(Opacityanimation);
    s.Begin();
}
```